# How to evaluate a string input and check if it is a decimal

Tags: python, string, input, decimal, evaluation

I use python 3 and am trying to figure out how to evaluate a user input string and check for certain characters.

I know that this title is probably going to make it sound like I haven't heard of the .isdecimal() method, but in fact I am trying to allow for a user to input some number as a decimal, including the period, and this is what seems to make the evaluation hard.

For instance,

dec = input()

dec.isdecimal()

Returns False if I have the input 0.5
I could convert the input to a decimal perhaps, but if I don't want to limit the user's input to whole numbers, I'm not sure how else I can approach this evaluation.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "is a decimal".  Maybe give some examples of what is and what is not (for you).  E.g '0', '1', '1.5', '1.0', 'x.y'...?

Comment: Maybe some context would help. This is for a program where I want the user to enter a percentage between 0 and 1, expressed as a decimal. So, 0.0 or 0.045 would be fine, but 3 would not, and neither would 'hello'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IIUC, you just want to check if your string has a decimal in it. In that case, you could simply do the following.

```
inp_string = input()

def check_decimal(inp_string):
    return ('.' in inp_string)

check_decimal(inp_string)
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot, and yes that's essentially what I am trying to do. Other users have aptly pointed out regex should work just fine, but in the spirit of the zen of python I would prefer simple code (not that I shouldn't brush up on regex too). Thanks for the elegant suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try parsing the string as a `float` and return `True` if successful?

```
def stringIsFloat(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use `Decimal` constructor

```py
from decimal import Decimal

user_input = input()
try:
    dec = Decimal(user_input)
except:
    dec = None
```

well you might choose to raise that error if the program execution is impossible after incorrect value has been entered.

Answer (score 0):

you asked a user `Enter number:` and user replied `oh man i think my number is 5.3, good?`

to extract the number `5.3` from this emotionally user answer, you should use `regex`

```
import re

text = 'oh man i think my number is 5.3, good?'
num = re.search(r'\d+.?\d+', text).group()
print(float(num))
```

output:

```
5.3
```